# How does an adaptive Gaussian threshold filter work?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, filtering

I have successfully implemented OpenCVs adaptive Gaussian thresholding on a Raspberry Pi. How does the algorithm (cross-correlation with a Gaussian window) actually work?

Reading through the documentation and searching online, I can't find anything that explains the operation of the function, only how to implement it (which I have already done) (https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html).

If it is of note, I am using this filter to improve the readability of a barcode reader I have developed on the Pi when in the presence of inconsistent lighting.

Answer (score 1):

What you call “cross-correlation with a Gaussian window” is actually supposed to be a convolution operation. The Gaussian is a low-pass filter. This means it suppresses the high-frequency content of the image, leaving only slow spatial variations. The idea is that the slow variations are mostly caused by illumination changes across the image, and high frequencies are caused by edges.

Another way to look at the filter is to see it as a local (weighted) averaging. Each output pixel is the weighted average of pixels in a neighborhood.

The threshold step thus compares a pixel value with the local average pixel value. Pixels with a relatively high value are then considered foreground, pixels with a relatively low value are considered background.

Contrast this with a normal threshold that compares to a fixed value for all pixels. By using a local average, we become independent of difference in illumination across the image.